# Data overwriting at same-time request using Mongoose and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I've got a following problem with my MEAN.js application. I'm trying to make some web-browser game. Players are planning attacks on barbarians castles, the attacks must be evaluated, so I've made a method for AttackSchema, which is responsible for that. This method is called everytime the user logs in or view an army moves window (in future I want to add a cron for that too). The problem is that when I plan for example 2 attacks on same barbarian castle, then logout and login after both attacks are evaluated, it overwrites barbarians "level up". See the code below & comments

---

**Method calling**

```
exports.listByUser = function(req, res) {
    Attack.find({user: req.user._id}, function(err, attacks) {
        if(err) 
            return next(err);
        for(var i in attacks) {
            attacks[i].evaluateFight(); //here it evaluates every user's attack, 
                                          which wasn't evaluated yet
        }
        res.json(attacks);
    });
};
```

**Method**

```
AttackSchema.methods.evaluateFight = function() {
    if(!this.result.evaluated && (this.arriveTime < Date.now())) {
        var player = {}, barbarian = {};
        var attack = this;
        mongoose.model('User').findOne({_id: this.user}, function(err, user) {
            mongoose.model('Game').findOne({_id: user.game}, function(err, game) {
                var barbarianQuery = _.find(game.barbarians, function(field) {
                    if(field._id.equals(attack.barbarian)) return true;
                });
                if(barbarianQuery) {
                    // perform an attack evaluation and update barbarian's castle in game
                        mongoose.model('Game').findOneAndUpdate( 
                            { '_id': game._id, 'barbarians._id': attack.barbarian },
                            { '$set': { 'barbarians.$': barbarianQuery } },
                            function(err, data) {
                                console.log(err);
                                console.log(data);
                            }
                        );
                        attack.save();
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

The second attack evaluation counts with same barbarian and then overwrites the result of first attack evaluation. For example at first player win - barbarian grows to level 2 and update, secondly player lose - barbarian is overwrited to level 1 again...
Is there any option to LOCK updated collections in mongoDB or another solution how to fix this bug? Thanks for answers!

Comment: Your evaluateFight method is asynchronous, which means that you'll execute the function once for every `attack` almost simultaneously, which is probably why things are getting overwitten. There are lots of ways to make sure that things happen in sequence, like [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) or smart use of callbacks

Comment: Yes, I got it 5 minutes ago, but thanks :-)